# Is there a possibility to use mysqlimport for timestamps-column?

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport, test-data

I have some timestamp-columns in my table who can be null, but i want to fill them with testdata through mysqlimport. 
Is there maybe a possibility to give the timestamp parameter through the testdata.txt?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `mysqlimport` will help you on this.  You have two choices (1) run `UPDATE` command on the table searching for the NULL values and replacing them with your desired values, or (2) find & replace the null values in the dump file.